Serialising a model with signals in Angular 18
I'm trying to serialise a model object to local storage (or IndexedDB), however it contains signals.
// An example of the model I'm dealing with
export class ExampleModel {
    canSerialise = "";
    cantSerialise = signal("");
}

// What I'd like to be able to do
let exampleModel = new ExampleModel();
localStorage.setItem("example", JSON.stringify(exampleModel));

However this will not serialise cantSerialise as signals are technically functions. I'd like to avoid manually writing serialisation functions for all models that just have a signal in them.

Tried simply serialising using JSON.stringify():

Desired outcome: '{"canSerialise":"","cantSerialise":X}' where X can be anything as long as it serialises back into the original value as a signal (in this case signal(""))
Results (as I feared/expected) in '{"canSerialise":""}'


Thought about using IndexedDB but it won't be able to serialise signals either since the structured cloning algorithms has the same limitation of nog serialising functions.

EDIT:
I should clarify the goals is for the model to be serialised and that said model happens to have signals in it, I'm given the model and can't change it. A the same time i would like to stress that deserialisation does need to result in having signals in the same places as before serialisation (e.g. cantSerialise should be wrapped in a signal during deserialisation but canSerialise should not) as the code dealing with the model (which again I don't have control over) expects those signals. The signals don't need to be the exact same signals per se i.e. just storing their value during serialisation and wrapping them in a new signal during deserialisation is acceptable.

Can you please explain your use case for why you would want to store a signal in localStorage?

You use TS, but did not provide appropriate tag in your question, on the other hand you use both signals and angular-signals tags. Also consider @Chellappanவ comment, to eliminate XY problem.

@Chellappan வ I've added some clarification above.

This is not perfect code, but you can write a custom toString method that executes the signal before writing to an object. Then we can call JSON.stringify to convert the object which contains only the values into a string.
Please ignore my TypeScript mistakes, since it's the best I can do; it might look ugly but it gets the job done.
export class ToStringConverter {
  toString() {
    let output: any = {};
    const that: ToStringConverter = this as never as ToStringConverter;
    for (let key in that) {
      if (that!.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const lookupKey: keyof ToStringConverter =
          key as keyof ToStringConverter;
        if ((that[lookupKey] as any) instanceof Function) {
          output[lookupKey] = (that[lookupKey] as Function)() as any;
        } else {
          output[lookupKey] = that[lookupKey];
        }
      }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(output);
  }
}

Full code:
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export class ToStringConverter {
  toString() {
    let output: any = {};
    const that: ToStringConverter = this as never as ToStringConverter;
    for (let key in that) {
      if (that!.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const lookupKey: keyof ToStringConverter =
          key as keyof ToStringConverter;
        if ((that[lookupKey] as any) instanceof Function) {
          output[lookupKey] = (that[lookupKey] as Function)() as any;
        } else {
          output[lookupKey] = that[lookupKey];
        }
      }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(output);
  }
}

// An example of the model I'm dealing with
export class ExampleModel extends ToStringConverter {
  canSerialise = '';
  cantSerialise = signal('');

  constructor(canSerialize = '', cantSerialize = '') {
    super();
    this.canSerialise = canSerialize;
    this.cantSerialise = signal(cantSerialize);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    // What I'd like to be able to do
    let exampleModel = new ExampleModel('working', 'also working');
    localStorage.setItem('example', exampleModel.toString());
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

This solution does partially succeed in that it serialises the signals but there is no distinction between a value that was wrapped in a signal and one that wasn't which means deserialisation cannot wrap signals around values where needed. As a wrote in my question it need to deserialise as a signal. I've used a modified version of your solution in which I prefix keys/properties with func_ or other_ so that when deserialising it I can just remove the prefix and wrap in a new signal where needed.

https://pastebin.com/H8VyspgA
